# Angularjs/Bootstrap 3 CSS text goes beyond background image

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the ng-view area powered by angular.
You can see the text extends beyond the background image.
How can i adjust the background image size pls ?
[image]

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(images/blue3.jpg)', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'height':'800px', 'background-size':'contain' }">
        <h1> {{message}} </h1>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed height on that element? Either let it grow to it's content with `height: auto;` or make the overflow scroll with `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: arjabbar, i set the background to be "repeat", then used "auto" instead of fixed height, it's not perfect, but works, :) Please "answer your question" so i can accept the answer. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Also, if the content has only 2 lines, the background is also very narrow given it's "auto" height now, any way to make it 800px or auto (if content has more lines) ? just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either let it grow to it's content with `height: auto;` or make the overflow scroll with `overflow-y: scroll;`